# Develop Snap-On Board For Easy Connections - Rabbit SBC

Tags: pic

At my Company, we are using the BL2600 ([Seen here](http://www.rabbit.com/products/bl2600/)) to create a new automation controller to replace our older controller. Rather than have electricians have to terminate wires into a Molex connector and snap on the side, we'd rather have boards snap into the sockets seen in the picture and then allow simple green screw-in connectors. How can we create this ourselves or purchase from somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the receptacles are in parallel with the Molex connectors. 
Is that true? Also it looks like the receptacles are top and bottom
entry.

If those are bottom entry then you could build a single interface
board that the Rabbit will plug into. The board would have long-pin
headers to interface to the Rabbit and screw terminals for your wires.
The interface board would also make replacing the Rabbit easier.

Are you sure Rabbit doesn't sell an accessory like this?
If you could purchase the board without the Molex connectors
you could probably solder on screw terminals.

Comment: We checked on Rabbit's website and it does not seem they sell it. The sockets are in parallel with the molex slots so they are one and the same.

Comment: Are the sockets bottom entry or just top entry? If they are bottom entry and there are no obstructions underneath a single interface  board with screw terminals around the periphery should be fairly easy to create. You should see if Rabbit has a dimensioned print. 

From the top you could do individual boards with a right angle header and a screw-terminal (which I believe was your original idea ;)

Comment: Yes, you can do top or bottom. I wouldn't even know where to create such a prototype board (I am a Embedded Software Engineer not Electrical / Hardware Engineer).. I imagine you can buy these boards somewhere? Do you have a link?

Comment: I am an Embedded Hardware Engineer so I would just make my own ;) 
If Rabbit doesn't sell something I am not sure. For my embedded boards I have been making a little screw terminal board. Scroll down to the bottom picture at http://wiblocks.luciani.org/NB2/index.html
If you changed the bottom connector to pins and scaled it properly something like that should work.

Comment: Yea I am really looking for something built already with screw terminals. Unless there is a prototype board already that has the terminals and you just have to solder the pins.